# retrieve neighbour entry via struct rt

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, ethernet, arp, neighbours

I'm working on a kernel module code, where I need to peek in to the
routing table to fetch ARP table entry for my `daddr`:

```
       |--------------------------------------------------|
-------+ enp0s1 192.168.2.0/24      192.168.3.0/24 enp0s2 +-----
       |--------------------------------------------------|
```

For example, I need to obtain `neighbour` entry for 192.168.3.111, and this entry has been permanently added in the table:

```
% ip neigh  add 192.168.3.111 lladdr 00:11:22:33:44:55 dev enp0s2 nud permanent
% ip neigh sh
...
192.168.3.111 dev enp0s2 lladdr 00:11:22:33:44:55 PERMANENT
% ip route show
...
192.168.3.0/24 dev enp0s2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.3.2
```

I came up with the following code:

```
struct rtable *rt;
struct flowi4 fl4;
struct dst_entry dst;
struct neighbour *neigh;
u8 mac[ETH_ALEN];

...
memset(&fl4, 0, sizeof fl4);
fl4.daddr = daddr;
fl4.flowi4_proto = IPPROTO_UDP;

rt = ip_route_output_key(net, &fl4);
if (IS_ERR(rt))
    goto err;

...
dst = rt->dst;
neigh = dst_neigh_lookup(&dst, &fl4.daddr);
if (!neigh) {
   ...
}

neigh_ha_snapshot(mac, neigh, neigh->dev);
neigh_release(neigh);
ip_rt_put(rt);
```

However `neigh_ha_snapshot` does not return correct `MAC` address, in fact I think it returns garbage, sometimes `ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`, sometimes multicast `01:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is fixed as follows:

```
neigh = dst_neigh_lookup(&rt->dst, &fl4.daddr);
```

So instead of having `struct dst_entry` object on the stack, assigning a value from `rt` and passing a pointer to it in `dst_neigh_lookup()`, just pass a a pointer to `dst` member in the current `rt` object.

The reason is withing the following code:

```
static inline struct neighbour *dst_neigh_lookup(const struct dst_entry *dst, const void *daddr)
{
        struct neighbour *n = dst->ops->neigh_lookup(dst, NULL, daddr);
        return IS_ERR(n) ? NULL : n;
}
```

where `neigh_lookup` is initialized to function `ipv4_neigh_lookup()` defined in `net/ipv4/route.c` :

```
static struct neighbour *ipv4_neigh_lookup(const struct dst_entry *dst,
                                           struct sk_buff *skb,
                                           const void *daddr)
{
        struct net_device *dev = dst->dev;
        const __be32 *pkey = daddr;
        const struct rtable *rt;
        struct neighbour *n;

        rt = (const struct rtable *) dst;
        ...
}
```

From this point `rt` is bogus and so is the rest.